# Why does shell script execute "then" block if the condition is 0?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell script and I am seeing something that I don't understand.

Consider the code below:

```
function test {
    return 0
}

if test; then
   echo "hihi"
fi
```

If I execute the code, it will call "hihi". If the test return 1, it will not call.

I am just wondering why?

Comment: Zero is true for *nix shells.

Answer (score 3):

In UNIX, an exit code of 0 is used to signal success, while a non-zero exit code signals some sort of error. You would read it as:

```
if operation_that_might_fail_succeeds; then
    echo "everything went ok!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a non-zero return value indicates some issue/error in Unix terminology, so if you replace the return 0 with some non-zero number you'll go into the else block

```
function test {
    return 1    # or any non-zero value
}

if test; then
   echo "hihi"
else
    echo 'else block'
fi
```

Output:

```
else block
```